# Multiple ImageButton objects where each launches a different website

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

Suppose one of my screens has multiple ImageButton objects and each one should launch a unique website when clicked. For example, if the ImageButtons featured pictures of various restaurant logos (Burger King, Wendys, etc) when the ImageButton featuring the Wendys logo was clicked "wendys.com" would open. If the id of each ImageButton was something like

```
android:id="@+id/wendys"
```

is there any way that my launchWebsite() method in java could look something along the lines of

```
public void launchWebsite(View view) {
    Intent openURL = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openURL.setData(Uri.parse("https://www." + [insert id here] + ".com"));
    startActivity(openURL);

}
```

Thanks so much in advance, I am relatively new to Android Studios

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a **onClickListener** for each ImageView and modify your method a little bit:

Change the parameter to pass a **String** (Do you need the view being passed? If yes, keep it there)

```
ImageButton ib_wendys = findViewById(R.id.ib_wendys);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchWebsite("wendys") //I would even consider to pass the whole URL since it could be different than .com
            }
        });
```

Method:

```
public void launchWebsite(String url) {
    Intent openURL = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openURL.setData(Uri.parse("https://www." + url + ".com"));
    startActivity(openURL);

}
```